# A phrase or word meaning "thin rationale"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to fill in the blank.

I feel like the president of the university had a ________ for demoting Mr. X.

The meaning I want to convey is "thin rationale". This might be the phrase I'm looking for, but it doesn't show up in a lot of search results.

What I mean is: A justification that might not hold up under scrutiny. A questionable justification for doing or saying something.

I hope I was clear, and I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Maybe *thin excuse*

Comment: Lame, poor excuse

Comment: A 'poor case' perhaps?

Comment: Leaky or loose case as the opposite of an airtight case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with "flimsy excuse".

**flimsy** - [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flimsy)

> adjective, *flimsier, flimsiest.*
>   1. without material strength or solidity:
>   *a flimsy fabric; a flimsy structure.*
>
> 2.weak; inadequate; not effective or convincing:
>   *a flimsy excuse.*

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for ***[pretext](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pretext):***

> - something that is put forward to conceal a true purpose or object; an ostensible reason; excuse:
>     *The leaders used the insults as a pretext to declare war.*

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but still extremely useful. Thanks for your response. +1

Answer (score 1):

**contestable** reasons/rationale might fit well here

- to call into question (dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

"Questionable motive" is a good fit.

**Questionable** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/questionable)

> 1.Doubtful as regards truth or validity
> *"it is questionable whether any of these exceptions is genuine"*
>
> 1.1. Likely to be dishonourable or morally suspect
> *"his questionable financial deals"*

**Motive** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motive)

> 1.A reason for doing something
> *"police were unable to establish a motive for his murder"*

<sub>Possible combinations:

*dubious/problematic/debatable/disputable/lame/thin* and *reason/excuse/grounds/cause/basis/purpose/intention*</sub>